# Javascript: retrieve cookies for a particular site

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible in Javascript to save your own cookies that relate to a particular site "www.example.com" and then you can reuse them in another browser?

For example: I save cookies for site "www.example.com" using Javascript in Chrome. I open Firefox and using Javascript I load these cookies and use them.

Comment: Short answer: *no*. JavaScript doesn't have access to the cookies that were set by another domain.

Comment: Do you want to do this for arbitrary sites or a specific site that belongs to you?

Comment: it's for my clients sites. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Directly no. But you could make a proxy. The scenario is:**

1. User go to webpage, it save cookies in DB
2. User change browser and open the same website (for ex. uniq url OR some kind of authentication)
3. Website loads cookies back from DB

**in php you can get all cookies using:**

```
print_r($_COOKIE)
```

**If your domain will send this header, your cookies will be avaliable from every domain:**

```
header('Content-type: text/html');    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

**It's not possible to read other domains cookies without their knowledge.** If it would be possible it would be security thread. (ex. spam websites read your login information from facebook.com)

Comment: greate! i think it can works, but how can i save cookies in DB? maybe php?

Comment: this works great!!! is there a way to do the same thing for various domains and subdomains?
for example i have there sites
"a.example.com" "b.example.com" "c.example.com"
and maybe another domain
"a.example2.com" "b.example2.com" "c.example2.com"
you can do the same thing in a single operation?
thank you very much

Comment: @Lgd yes, check this http://www.jotlab.com/2008/howto-get-cookies-across-subdomains-php

Comment: Thank you for your big help! last question. it's possible to retrive cookies of a different domain? for example i'm on "www.example.com" domain and i want to retrive the "www.anotherdomain.com" cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There's no JavaScript facilities that are shared between different browsers. You need to use some other storage like Flash for that.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser saves its cookies to his own cookie directory. They usually don't share this with each other, altough you may could set up each browser individually to use one shared cookie directory in which each browser saves its cookies.

As a cookie is nothing else than a text file, each browser should be able to read this if there is no particular difference in the implementation of how the browser saves the cookie to the file system.

If the cookies are compressed or written in other encoding types for example, it won't work.